# How can i load a menu into multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file called menu.html which is basically a dropdown i want to put on each of my html pages, how would i achieve this?

```
<div class="topbar">
    <a href="./index.html">
        Home
    </a>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#content").load("menu.html");
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using any framework? A master page or partial view is what you need

Comment: Have you tried looking into Single Page Web Apps?

Comment: @JustinJmnz are single page web apps better than whatever junk im doing right now?

Comment: @TalkingMango They all have their own implementations. If you want to stay closely related to traditional webpages you can look into https://angularjs.org/. It's easier to follow then the newer https://angular.io/. Both will do what you want with minimal experience. A couple of hours of practice and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I just answered because I thought I saw you had tagged this with php. Is php your server-side code, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention php as your server-side code, I would highly recommend using [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) Injecting with javascript is not a good idea, as it will be quite slow.

Twig is what is called a "templating system". With twig, you can create a template that has the menu html:

**menu.html**

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Then in your page html, you can "include" menu.html:

**page.html**

```
{% include 'menu.html' %}

<!-- your page content here -->
```

Twig is very powerful; it does things like automatic escaping to make sure user input is safe to view, multiple inheritance, content blocks, etc.